# Submitting form through Javascript to PHP not working

Tags: javascript, php, pdo, xmlhttprequest

Can someone point me in  the right direction. I'm not sure why this isn't submitting into my database. I'm trying to create a chat for my website and I can't seem to get this to work properly.

My form:

```
<form onsubmit="return sendMessage();" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <input type="text" class="input_custom" id="Message"> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-default">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My JS:

```
function sendMessage() {
   var message = escape(document.getElementById("Message").value);
   var send = new XMLHttpRequest();
   send.open("GET", "index.php"+"?message="+message, true);
   send.send();
   return false;
}
```

My PHP:

```
$sucess = '';
if(isset($_GET['message'])) {
    $message = $_GET['message'];
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date2 = $date->format('l h:i A"');
    $user = $username;
    if(!empty($message)) {
        $db->prepare("INSERT INTO shouts (date, username, shout) VALUES (:date, :username, :shout)");
        $db->execute(array(':date' => $date2, ':username' => $user, ':shout' => $message));
        $sucess = 'shout sent.';
    }
}
```

Comment: check for errors, check your console.

Answer (score 0):

See [runnable](http://code.runnable.com/Vl-lkt6ELZx-FZyf/submitting-form-through-javascript-to-php-not-working).

Seems your code works :)

Some possible issues ('i'v pointed to them via comments'):

1. $username variable is undefined, so some sql-constaints prevent inserting row
2. DB connection is not set.
3. Some other db related problems. See [link about get errors from pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php).

Comment: Sorry, I just posted the code snippets, I have included my config for connection and the $username variable at the top.